# Multi-level preprocessor macro messing up string-ized output

Tags: c++, visual-c++, googletest, c-preprocessor

We build a MSVC++ unit testing project under 2 different configurations, to run the same tests against different implementations. As each test is run twice, we hack the test-name using preprocessor ugliness:

```
#if defined(XXX)
    #define _VER BUILDX
#elif defined(YYY)
    #define _VER BUILDY
#endif

#define _TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package) Suite##_##Package
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package) _TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package)
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME(Suite) TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,_VER)

#define TEST(test_case_name, test_name) GTEST_TEST(TEST_SUITE_NAME(test_case_name), test_name)
```

This all works perfectly, redefining the google-test `TEST` macro to modify the test-suite name using stringify tricks.

But the following does *not* work:

```
#define TEST_F(test_fixture, test_name)\
  GTEST_TEST_(TEST_SUITE_NAME(test_fixture), test_name, test_fixture, \
              ::testing::internal::GetTypeId<test_fixture>())
```

Instead of output like `StringTestSuite_XXX.EqualityTest` using `TEST(StringTestSuite,EqualityTest)`, using `TEST_F` gives output like:

`TEST_SUITE_NAME(StringTestSuite).EqualityTest`

Can I get this working with some simple-ish tweaks?

For reference, here is the gtest code for [GTEST_TEST_](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h?r=566#1197). And in gtest.h, `GTEST_TEST` is defined as:

```
#define GTEST_TEST(test_case_name, test_name)\
  GTEST_TEST_(test_case_name, test_name, \
              ::testing::Test, ::testing::internal::GetTestTypeId())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add one more macro to achieve one more level of indirection, so that macro will be evaluated on that level:

```
#define TEST_F_I(test_fixture, test_name, original_name) \
    GTEST_TEST_(test_fixture, test_name, original_name, \
         ::testing::internal::GetTypeId<original_name>())

#define TEST_F(test_fixture, test_name) \
    TEST_F_I(TEST_SUITE_NAME(test_fixture), test_name, test_fixture)
```

[My macro live demo link.](http://ideone.com/EnyMP1)

[Your macro live demo link.](http://ideone.com/AP5F7g)